# CSS: master stylesheet with multiple imports, or multiple stylesheets?

Tags: css

I've always created one stylesheet called `master.css`, imported this one stylesheet, in the `<head>`, and used `@import` statements to pull in other stylesheets, e.g.

```
@import('sitestyles.css')
@import('blogstyles.css')
```

I copied this from other people.

But I've just been asked why I do this rather than simply importing both stylesheets in the `<head>`, and realised I don't know.

Anyone know a good reason why one is preferable to another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say in the head is preferable - you can see at a glance which CSS is included without having to dig into the CSS files themselves.

Comment: Actually, Google page speed guidelines recommend this too: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#PutCSSInHead

Answer (score 1):

I do this because it just creates less HTML for me to maintain. I have a standard reset.css file that I include in all my sites, then my screen.css and any others I may need, such as those for jQuery plugins and so on. The down side is that you may include unnecessary stylesheets, and increase load times.

Also, with the addition of CSS3 @media query it will make everything a lot more maintanable in my opinion. `@media (orientation: portrait) { … }`

```
@media screen{
  /* Import all stylesheets for screen */
}

@media (orientation: portrait){
      /* Import all stylesheets for portrait layouts */
}
```

And so on

This is purely just opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

If your master.css doesn't change dynamically, why not just include all the styles in one file? If it does change dynamically (depending on what page the user is viewing), then surely it'd be easier to include the different stylesheets in the head rather than having to alter master.css dynamically. That way, you can see straight away what files are included.

Comment: Some files are shared between multiple sites, so I can't just use one file. Thanks though.